# webview doesn't show URL

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I am new to iOS development, i am trying to use a `UIWebView` using the following code

```
import UIKit
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var myWebView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.chrisharrisracing.com/twitterapp.php");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

However when I build the the web page is not displayed, although when I go to the web address in a browser the page works fine, any help would be appreciated

Comment: is it giving any error / warning

Answer (score 0):

I just created a sample project to check your issue and its working for me.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.chrisharrisracing.com/twitterapp.php");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj);

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

If you want you can  download the sample project from the following link

```
https://www.dropbox.com/home/SAMPLE%20GIT%20PROJECTS%20%5BSHARED%5D/WEBVIEW?preview=webViewSample.zip
```

You should add NSTransportSecurity to info.plist

HOPE THIS HELPS.....

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample project with your code and it works just fine. The only difference is that I didn't use the second outlet (@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!) you have in this code. My guess is you haven't added any constraints for your webview and that's why you can't see it. So go to your storyboard choose your webview and then go to the triangle icon at the bottom right and choose Add missing constraints.

[image: Add missing constraints]

[image: App running]

Of course make sure your internet connection is ok and that you have added the allow arbitrary loads key in your info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't added your constraints yet, which is why `myWebView` might not be visible. Or maybe, this is probably a longshot, but I've noticed that you have another unused UIWebView called `webView`. Maybe, just maybe, `webView` is covering up `myWebView`, thus you aren't seeing myWebView loading the page.